# JUnit without Eclipse : how to get the TestRunner Window

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I followed a tutorial here to execute a test runner out of Eclipse :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

Nevertheless when test fails it outputs in the console, not in popup Window like this:

[image]

Can I change the code below to get that popup Window ?

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestJunit.class);
      for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
         System.out.println(failure.toString());
      }
      System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not clear to me. The title says that you want to run the problem without eclipse, but you said that you did the setup in eclipse? What do you want: green and red tests in eclipse - or green and red tests on the console?

Comment: @CoronA OK I updated : when I say Console, I mean DOS or command line console. I do not use Eclipse I want to learn the hard way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-runners) there is no support for a graphical runner that could be run from console (older versions of JUnit had one, but it was probably not used too often).

But there are integrated runners for Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ. To start them in your IDE go to the test class, e.g. `TestJunit`, right-click, and select `run as JUnit Test` (or similar).

The alternative is to use the console runner typing `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestJunit`